# .htaccess Rewrite for multiple directories

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to use htaccess to rewrite by checking multiple directories and not just one?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

I have 2 files
site.com/profile.php?username1
site.com/project.php?projectname1

I would like to make it where the person only has to type in something like:

site.com/NAME -> the "NAME" can be whatever they choose it to be, either the username1 or projectname1, doesn't matter.

Now the issue that I'm having is can htaccess search through both profile AND project to match the name that the user types in and redirect the user to the proper file?

To clarify....if the person types in site.com/username1.....will it automatically know to go to PROFILE.php?username1?

if the person types in site.com/projectname1.....will it automatically know to go to PROJECT.php?projectname1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use htaccess to do this, because mod_rewrite doesn't know anything about the process of what makes the **NAME** a profile or a project, only the two php scripts know anything about that. What you're better off doing is writing some routing code in something like `router.php` or even `index.php`, then route everything through it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /router.phpname=$1 [L]
```

Then in your `router.php` script, see if the `$_GET['name']` is a profile or a project, then route it to either the `profile.php` or `project.php` as it sees fit.